# Which images can be used universally across all Raspberry Pi versions?

Tags: image, arm

My search failed this time so I'm asking here.

Are there images that universally can be used across all Raspberry Pi versions?
Original, 2, B+ 3, etc. For Armv6 and Armv7 architecture

If they do exist can you point me in the right direction?

The idea is that one image gets deployed for older and newer Raspberry Pi so a non-technical person will not need to determine which Raspberry Pi they have.

Comment: Where did you see images specific to a particular RPi?

Comment: CentOS for example only lists Raspberry Pi3, hence where my confusion originated from

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All images available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ are compatible with all Pi models.

Of course, this may change in the future

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of Raspberry Pi supported releases:

- `| Model | First Version (FV) | FV Release Date    | End of Support |`
- `| 3+    | Stretch            | April 18th, 2018   | Pending        |`
- `| 3     | Jessie             | Febuary 29th, 2016 | Pending        |`
- `| 2/2+  | Wheezy             | Febuary 2nd, 2015  | Pending        |`
- `| 1/1+  | Wheezy             | July 15th, 2012    | Pending        |`

Sources:

- [Raspbian Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian#Version_history)
- [Official Raspbian Archive](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/)

Comment: At the time of posting your answer, the latest Raspbian was actually the June '18 release. First Raspbian release must have been around May / June 2012. The wiki page is clearly not fully up to date.

Comment: @Dirk Ah, I see. It did seem kind of odd that the first recorded Raspbian release was a Wheezy version from 2013... I'll update.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll keep an eye out for that wiki article